# Troubleshooting performance issues with capybara and poltergeist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

Originally posted this on the capybara google group, but I think this is a more appropriate place since it may be more poltergeist related.

I am having some performance issues when using poltergeist/phantomjs for headless browser testing.. The specs below log in a user and hit a page w/ very little load, but take a *very* long time to run. Using poltergeist as the driver more than doubles the time it takes to run the spec compared to using selenium or chrome as the driver. I would expect the opposite to be true: that using poltergeist as the driver would decrease test times since the browser is headless.

Using: phantomjs 1.9.7, capybara 2.3.0, poltergeist 1.5.1, rspec 2.99, rails 4.1.4

I get the following results:

```rb
 # ~ 13 seconds
  scenario "with js - poltergeist", :js => true, driver: :poltergeist do
    login_as user
    visit work_on_stories_path

    expect(true).to be_true
  end

# ~ 5 seconds
  scenario "with js 2 - selenium", :js => true, driver: :selenium do
    login_as user
    visit work_on_stories_path

    expect(true).to be_true
  end

# ~ 5 seconds
  scenario "with js 3 - chrome", :js => true, driver: :chrome do
    login_as user
    visit work_on_stories_path

    expect(true).to be_true
  end

# ~ < .5 seconds
  scenario "without js" do
    login_as user
    visit work_on_stories_path

    expect(true).to be_true
  end
```

Are these normal results? Are there ways to improve them? What are common pitfalls that could result in these types of test run times?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't directly address your question because I use poltergeist in Cucumber, not RSpec, but my scenarios still call capybara and usually take less than a second, so no, this doesn't seem normal to me. I'd start looking in to what RSpec/capybara/poltergeist are doing in detail during a request and timing each step to see what's happening.

Comment: there's a timeout setting that you should google for - if you set that high, it will wait the full timeout length for every single thing - which does awful things for your performance.

Comment: @TarynEast I know about the timeout feature, but I'm asking about performance discrepancies running the same spec (that loads a basic page w/ no network calls) with multiple different drivers